# Native app in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, web-applications

I want to make a webapp with Laravel. When I click on a link, I want the browser to stay on the same page, but load new content. It is often used in other webapps, but I don't know how it works. Could someone explain it to me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at building SPAs (single page applications) in javascript. There are frameworks like Vuejs and React to make your life a little easier. Take a look at the laracasts series on Vue as a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

That is done via a frontend Framework. You could use pure Vuejs with some of its official packages or you could use Vuejs within Laravel which ships it out by default.

The Laravel implementation would look something like this:
Vuejs component makes HTTP/API call through axios or vue-resource libraries>Laravel receives the call defined mainly in the api.php file and routes it to the appropiate controller.

The Vuejs implemantation is similar at the begining. It makes an HTTP API request through one of the libraries but you'll not be able to persist data in your server(Unless, if for some strange reason you build the two projects separately).

Anyway, you'll have to learn Vuejs, React or other Frontend Framework.

Search for some projects and tutorials using queries like 'vuejs larval todo', 'vuejs larvel crud' and 'vuejs crud'